# How are vtables implemented in c++ and c#?

Tags: c#, c++, inheritance, interface, vtable

Lets have this situation (in c++, in c# classes A,B are interfaces):

```
class A { virtual void func() = 0; };
class B { virtual void func() = 0; };
class X: public A, public B { virtual void func(){ var = 1; } int var;};

X * x = new X; // from what I know, x have 2 vtables, is this the same in c#?
A * a = (A*)x; // a == x
B * b = (B*)x; // here b != x, so when calling b->func(), how is the address of var correct?
```

Does the c# compiler create always one vtable? Does it make any pointer fixups when casting?

Comment: I suppose you mean `a == x` and `b != x`. Since pointers are allocated one after the other on stack, they all have a distinct address ... althought they should all point towards the same object.

Comment: of course, my mistake :) It's fixed now, I forgot that a == b compares addresses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not to be overly pedantic, but the C# compiler does not get involved at this level. The Entire type model, inheritance, interface implementation etc. is actually handled by the CLR more specifically the CTS (Common Type System). .NET compilers mostly just generate IL code that represents intent which is later executed by the CLR where all Vtable handling etc. is taken care of.

For some detail on how the CLR creates and manages runtime types the following link will be a good starting point. Towards the end the MethodTable and Interface Maps are explained.

http://web.archive.org/web/20150515023057/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx

Comment: This link is broken now -- it just goes to an index of back issues of MSDN magazine.  To see the original article, download the .CHM file for May 2005, unblock it, and then go to the article "JIT and Run: Drill Into .NET Framework Internals to See How the CLR Creates Runtime Objects."  (Alternatively, google the title.)  I'd edit in a link but there doesn't seem to be an "official" one.

Comment: Thanks, I replaced the link with a link to the original article via the wayback time machine.

Answer (score 3):

If I study this derived version with g++

```
class X: public A, public B { 
   unsigned magic;
 public:
   X() : magic(0xcafebabe) {};
   virtual void func(){ var = 1; } int var;
};

extern "C" int main() 
{
   X * x = new X; // from what I know, x have 2 vtables, is this the same in c#?
   A * a = (A*)x; // &a == &x
   B * b = (B*)x; // here &b != &x, so when calling b->func(), how is the address of var correct?
   printf("%p -- %p -- %p\n", x, a, b);

   unsigned* p = (unsigned*)((void*) x);
   unsigned *q = (unsigned*)(p[1]);
   printf("x=[%x %x %x %x]\n",p[0],p[1],p[2],p[3]);
   p = (unsigned*)(p[0]);
   printf("a=[%x %x %x %x]\n",p[0],p[1],p[2],p[3]);
   printf("b=[%x %x %x %x]\n",q[0],q[1],q[2],q[3]);

}
```

It turns out that, in C++ b == a+1, so the structure for X is [vtable-X+A][vtable-B][magic][var]
inspecting deeper (nm ./a.out), vtable-X+a contains the reference towards X::func (as one would expect). when you casted your X into B, it adjusted the pointers so that the VTBL for B functions appears where the code expects it.

Did you actually intend to "hide" B::func() ?

B's vtbl looks like holding a reference towards a "trampoline" to X that restores the object pointer to a full X before calling the "regular" X::func that X+A vtbl holds.

```
080487ea <_ZThn8_N1X4funcEv>:   # in "X-B vtbl"
_ZThn8_N1X4funcEv():
 80487ea:       83 44 24 04 f8          addl   $0xfffffff8,0x4(%esp)
 80487ef:       eb 01                   jmp    80487f2 <_ZN1X4funcEv>
 80487f1:       90                      nop

080487f2 <_ZN1X4funcEv>:        # in X-A vtbl
_ZN1X4funcEv():
 80487f2:       55                      push   %ebp
 80487f3:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80487f5:       8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
 80487f8:       c7 40 14 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,0x14(%eax)
 80487ff:       5d                      pop    %ebp
 8048800:       c3                      ret
```

Comment: Did you really just `extern "C"` main?

Comment: Hmm ... dunno. Looks like that's not something I usually do in my other C++ tools. That only affects name mangling and external visibility, right ?

Comment: So much fun here))

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is only ever one v-table in a managed language, the CLR does not support multiple inheritance.  There is a pointer fixup when you cast to an implemented interface.

This is a notable problem when trying to declare a COM interface that is itself declared from another interface beyond IUnknown.  An issue not quite understood by [this article's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188741.aspx#S4) author.  COM requires a *separate* v-table for each interface, just what a compiler that supports MI does.

Comment: If there is only one vtable, how c# supports diamond interface inheritance?

Comment: @Chris, if you take a look at the link I provided in my answer you should get a basic idea of how this works. Here is a quote "The duplication of slots is necessary to create an illusion that each interface has its own mini vtable. However, the duplicated slots point to the same physical implementation."

Comment: The diamond causes trouble because it becomes ambiguous which *implementation* to use.  An interface has no implementation.  There can only be one base class.

Answer (score 1):

vtables are an implementation detail.  There is no official/required/expected implementation.  Different compiler vendors can implement inheritance differently.