# virtual table every instance get's on or every object?

Tags: c#, c++

i have read about this metrial and i am still dont understand it's core
e.g:

```
public static void Main()
{
    person []p = new person[]{new student(),new worker()}; 
}

public class person
{
    public void f1() { }
    public virtual void f2() { }
} 
public class student:person
{
     public override void f2() { }
}

public class worker:person
{
    public override void f2() { }
}
```

does p[0] has it's own virtual table as an instance and so p[1] with one entry with f2 so every instance has it's own virtual table ?

does every object has it's own virtual table ?

Comment: Removed C++ tag as the OP's code is only C#.

Comment: @DeadMG this question is for them both even thoght the example is c#

Comment: See also related question here -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634660/how-are-vtables-implemented-in-c-and-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtual table is tied to object's type (i.e. class). But every object (instance of a reference type) has a pointer to its type, and therefore indirectly to its vtable.

If you are interested in C#, there is a neat article here which describes .NET CLR internals: [CodeProject .NET Type internals](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/net_type_internals.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Typically, there is only one vtable per type, and then each object contains a pointer to it's type's vtable. However, I believe that most inheritance implementations are undefined - i.e., it could be implemented in any way that it chooses.

Comment: @Steve Townsend: It's valid for both, afaik, although the OP's code is only C#.

Answer (score 1):

There's a comprehensive overview of how the CLR handles this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx#S10).

> How the CLR Creates Runtime Objects

For C++ it's [implementation-defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674929/c-v-table-part-of-the-language-or-compiler-dependent) - @DeadMG's answer is a good general guideline, though there are interesting edge cases like [multiple inheritance](http://hacksoflife.blogspot.com/2007/02/c-objects-part-3-multiple-inheritance.html) and [inline virtual functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733737/are-inline-virtual-functions-really-a-non-sense).

Comment: +1 for implementation defined: I've seen vftables get inlined into objects instead of a pointer to the vftable being set, iirc that was from some dodgy msvc code or something...

Comment: @Necrolis - possible due to Microsoft-specific `__declspec(novtable)` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k13k85ky(v=VS.100).aspx. Another edge case, thanks.